# Hibernate lazy property with projections

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate-projections

If you have your bean MyClass with a lot of properties.

If you want to lazy get one property with `@Basic( fetch=lazy)` you need to instrument your class right?

but

what if you do a projection over your bean and then do a `ResultTransformer(TransFormers.aliasToBean(MyClass.class))`

Something like this:

```
 /*.get(Usuario.class, 1); this gets the wholeobject with out @Basic(fetch=lazy)*/
     Usuario usuario = (Usuario) session 
    .createCriteria(Usuario.class)
    .add(Restrictions.eq("id", 1))
    .setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
    .add(Projections.property("id").as("id")))
           .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Usuario.class))
    .uniqueResult();
```

That does the trick. You got only the ID and not the whole object.

My question is. This Object of `Usuario` is the same in the query cache, and cache as if i get it with `.get()`?

Image you got another Object and that you need to put a relationship with usuario.

```
   // projected Usuario object
   AnotherObject.setUsuario(usuario);
   // this works okay, but its correct?
```

Thank you.

Comment: To save a relationship works as normal, but then if u want to get an another property that is an asociation whit Usuario like: usuario.getOtherObject(), this cant be done, hibernate cant load from the database. To solve this u need to include the asosiated object in the projection.